# rights protected photo on android

Tags: android

I've been tasked with writing an iphone application that displays a set of images (think powerpoint slideshow).  The content of these images need to be protected from forwarding

this task seems quite simple with one exception - I'd like to prevent the user from taking a screenshot

it's not like i'm protecting the crown jewels here, so I'm not looking for military grade super ninja protection.

thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has the Android SDK, they can take a screenshot. There is nothing you can do to stop it.

OTOH, without the Android SDK, there is no way to take a screenshot in Android.